# How to get the output of shell script into a variable in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, shell

I am trying to run a shell script inside my node js application and store the output of the shell script into a variable. I have the following code:

```
let run_number = parseInt(supervisor_row["producerState"].rows[0]["Run Number"]);
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourscript = exec('sh run.sh run_number',
    (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        console.log(`${stdout}`);
        console.log(`${stderr}`);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
        }
    });
```

As you can see first I am getting the run_number in the first line. Next, I am trying to run the shell script inside a child_process. I am passing the run_number as an input to the shell script. The shell script returns a string. I want to store the output of the shell script inside a variable. Can I do it simply by let somestr = ${stdout};. Please help.

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-streams-everything-you-need-to-know-c9141306be93

Comment: No you can't, cause  the exec is async, you should get the output only after the stdio streams are closed

Answer (score 0):

Try [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) npm package, but this would mean copy over your run.sh into javascript.